# Issues using scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment in which we are suppose to create a program for book store helping them to estimate their business. For that, we are suppose to ask user for all sorts of inputs such as a code for the book, the single copy cost for the book, the current number of books on hand, the prospective class enrollment, and so on. However, I am facing issues when user inputs invalid entry, such as when there is invalid entry for prospective enrollment, the program starts asking question from beginning instead of asking same question again.

Can anyone help me find out what am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

**Thanks in advance.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to College Store Sale Class.");
    System.out.println("Please enter all the info below as asked.");
    System.out.println("Write either 'Continue' or 'Exit' to continue or exit program respectively. ");



    double bookCost;
    int bookAvailable;
    String ending = sc.next();
    int prosepectiveEnrollment;
    String rOrO;    
    String nOrU;

    while(!ending.equals("exit")){



        System.out.print("Please enter the cost of book ($>=0). ");
        bookCost = sc.nextDouble();

        if(bookCost >= 0){

            System.out.print("Please enter the number of books available (n>=0). ");
            bookAvailable = sc.nextInt();

            if(bookAvailable >= 0){

                System.out.print("Please enter prospective class enrollement > 0: ");                   
                prosepectiveEnrollment = sc.nextInt();

                if(prosepectiveEnrollment > 0){

                    System.out.print("Is the book Required or Optional (ignoreCase)? ");
                    rOrO = sc.next();

                    if((rOrO.equalsIgnoreCase("Required") || rOrO.equalsIgnoreCase("Optional"))){

                        System.out.print("Is the book New or Used? Enter in 'N' or 'U' format. ");
                        nOrU = sc.next();
                        if((nOrU.equalsIgnoreCase("New") || nOrU.equalsIgnoreCase("Used"))){

                            System.out.println("Thanks for correct info, below is your result");

                        }

                        else{

                            System.out.println("(E) Please enter either 'New' or 'Used'. ");
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        System.out.println("(D) Please enter either 'Required' or 'Optional'. ");
                    }

                }
                else{

                    System.out.println("(C) Number of prospective class enrollement must be > 0.");
                }
            }
            else{

                System.out.println("(B) Number of books should be >= 0.");
            }

        }

        else{

            System.out.println("(A) Cost should be >= 0. ");
        }
    }

    if(ending.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
        System.out.println("See ya later..!! Bbyee..");
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: `I am facing issues when user inputs invalid entry, can anyone help me find out what am I doing wrong`, we can´t tell you what´s wrong when we don´t know the issue.

Comment: You should be getting exceptions thrown out of main if the user enters, say, "A" instead of an `int`. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @Scovetta No, lets say,

`Please enter the cost of book ($>=0). **1**`
`Please enter the number of books available (n>=0). **1**`
`Please enter prospective class enrollment > 0: **-1**`
`_(C) Number of prospective class enrollment must be > 0._`
`Please enter the cost of book ($>=0). `

Do you see here the pattern of repeating? If user has invalid entry for prospective enrollment then rather than asking same question it asks for entering the cost of book again which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to solve this, may be you can do it this way and let me know if this works for you

```
    public class Questionaire {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double bookCost = 0.0;
        int bookAvailable = 0;
        int prosepectiveEnrollment = 0;
        String rOrO = "";    
        String nOrU = "";

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.println("Welcome to College Store Sale Class.");
            System.out.println("Please enter all the info below as asked.");
            System.out.println("Write either 'Continue' or 'Exit' to continue or exit program respectively. ");

            String ending = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Your response "+ending);

            while(!ending.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){

                bookCost = promptQuestion("Please enter the cost of book ($>=0).", param -> {
                    return param >= 0;
                }, bookCost,sc);
                System.out.println("Your response "+bookCost);

                bookAvailable = promptQuestion("Please enter the number of books available (n>=0). ", param -> {
                    return param >= 0;
                }, bookAvailable, sc);
                System.out.println("Your response "+bookAvailable);

                prosepectiveEnrollment = promptQuestion("Please enter prospective class enrollement > 0: ", param -> {
                    return param > 0;
                }, prosepectiveEnrollment, sc);
                System.out.println("Your response "+prosepectiveEnrollment);

                rOrO = promptQuestion("Is the book Required or Optional (ignoreCase)? ", param -> {
                    return param.equalsIgnoreCase("Required") || param.equalsIgnoreCase("Optional");
                }, rOrO, sc);
                System.out.println("Your response "+rOrO);

                nOrU = promptQuestion("Is the book New or Used? Enter in 'N' or 'U' format. ", param -> {
                    return (param.equalsIgnoreCase("New") || param.equalsIgnoreCase("Used")
                            || param.equalsIgnoreCase("N") || param.equalsIgnoreCase("U"));
                }, nOrU, sc);
                System.out.println("Your response "+nOrU);

                System.out.println("Write either 'Continue' or 'Exit' to continue or exit program respectively. ");
                ending = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Your response "+ending);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static Integer promptQuestion(String question, Validation<Integer> validation, Integer input, Scanner sc) {
        do {
            System.out.println(question);
            input = sc.nextInt();
        } while(!validation.validate(input));
        return input;
    }

    static Double promptQuestion(String question, Validation<Double> validation, Double input, Scanner sc) {
        do {
            System.out.println(question);
            input = sc.nextDouble();
        } while(!validation.validate(input));
        return input;
    }

    static String promptQuestion(String question, Validation<String> validation, String input, Scanner sc) {
        do { 
            System.out.println(question);
            input = sc.next();
        } while(!validation.validate(input));
        return input;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private static interface Validation<T> {
        boolean validate(T t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however as this is an intro class, we are not yet suppose to do in the way you did as we haven't studied in detailed yet. For example we haven't studied what Integer in Validation<Integer> validation means.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the questions in a loop. When one of your conditions fails, the program continues past ALL subsequent conditions (if they are also incorrect) and begins the LOOP again. To correct this, you might have each condition occur within a loop. Something like

while(false condition answered):
           Ask again

To challenge yourself (and improve), keep the code to as few lines as possible!

Best of luck on your coding journey :)

Comment: That's what I did initially. I used nested while loop but it doesn't work. I can show you screen shot of nested while loop but I don't know how to post pic here as I can't find any attachment button.